# laravel full-text search with multiple keywords together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, full-text-search

i am building a laravel project search field where i use a full-text search.  I have managed to get this to work, but i cannot get multiple keywords to search together.
example:
i have a row with a value of `one two three four` if i search `two three` it finds all entries with either `two` or `three` in them.  But i want it to find the entry with both `two` and `three`

SQL query:

```
DB::raw("select id, name, text, image, publishDate from game
where match (name) AGAINST ('*$searchphrase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 5")
```

Comment: or eventually if it is possible to sort it so that phrases that include both keywords are listed at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this: http://goo.gl/lZIKBk at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

> "+" stands for AND
>
> "-" stands for NOT
>
> [no operator] implies OR

You don't have any operator which implied "OR".

---

Comment: I originally tried: with "+", but it didnt seem to make any difference. tried with "+" both before and after $searchphrase.

Comment: try "+" between the search phrase. Like "+apple +banana +orange".

Comment: got it working :) i only used the match against in the where.  Ended up sorting by relevance and it worked. turned out like this: select Id, Name, Text, Image, PublishDate, match(Name) against ('$searchphrase') as Relevance from game where match (Name) AGAINST ('+*$searchphrase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status = 1 order by Relevance desc LIMIT 5"  Although now it seems like i can search with an incomplete word like "upgr" finds upgrade but "grade" wont find "upgrade"